# Connecting Logitech F310 gamepad to Arduino Uno and Arduino USB Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

I am trying to connect Logitech F310 gamepad to Arduino Uno with ARDUINO USB HOST SHIELD https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-usb-host-shield using http://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0 library.

The closest is https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/tree/master/examples/HID/USBHIDJoystick example
After compiling there is no print output in serial window after "Start".
Tried keyboard sketch on same board - it worked.

There is "Mode" button on joystick - by pressing green led is switched ON and OFF.
Behind the joystick there is switch between "X" and "D" .
On "D" green led is working, on "X" - not.

Is this joystick even compatible with HID library? Is there other way how to configure it to USB shield? 
Joystick is working on different other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I found it here : https://github.com/AlanFord/Logitech_F310_and_Arduino
So there is a glitch in library and driver customization was necessary

Comment: It's OK to accept your own answer as the solution to the problem. I think you get 15 rep for it.